# Callling business logic layer method from PageMethods

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asmx, pagemethods

I've a static page method in web form application and I want to call method on private class level variable from it as shown below. I'm using jQuery to call the page method.

```
private readonly ICatalogBLL _catalogBLL = new CatalogBLL();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    _catalogBLL.GetSomething();
  }
}

[WebMethod]
public static UpdateSomething(int i)
{
   //Want to do as below. But can't call it from a static method.
   _catalogBLL.UpdateSomething();
}
```

**UPDATE**
If I call it as said by John Saunders, won't it use the same instance for requests from different users as it is within a static method?

Comment: you can use it for different users by just passing `userId`...

Comment: No meaning in exposing userId in javascript. It will be dangerous as anyone can fire javascript by passing random userIds

Comment: you misunderstood my point i told to pass it in the web method and not in the javascript...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The page method is static. Your `_catalogBLL` is an instance member.

However, since you create a new instance of `CatalogBLL` on every request, why not do so once more?

```
[WebMethod]
public static UpdateSomething(int i)
{
   CatalogBLL catalogBLL = new CatalogBLL();
   catalogBLL.UpdateSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call because pagemethods are static...

A static method is simply one that is disassociated from any instance of its containing class. The more common alternative is an instance method, which is a method whose result is dependent on the state of a particular instance of the class it belongs to.

Look at John saunder's answer..